# Camel SFTP File Download - copy of file is moved to client but actual file is present in Server

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp

I have a requirement to download file from external SFTP Server. I have service which has API hosted and once we hit API it should download the file from SFTP Server and I'm using camel as integrator for downloading the files from server. Now when API is called route is started and file is copied from source (server) to destination (client) but the sftp route is not closed, still it fetches the file from server and since the file is present in the server. How to solve this, below is the code snippet.

API Code

```
@GetMapping("myapicall")
public void fetchFileFromSFTPServer() {
    logger.info("-------Begin of fetchFileFromSFTPServer-------");
    try {
        RouteBuilder routeBuilder = sftpRoute.buildRoute();
        camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error while loading Routes------" + e.getMessage());
    }
    
    camelContext.setUseMDCLogging(true);
    logger.info("-------End of fetchFileFromSFTPServer-------" );
}
```

Route Builder Code

```
public RouteBuilder buildRoute() {
    RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            
            from(
              "sftp://server/?username=**&password=**&passiveMode=true&disconnect=true")
              .routeId("SFTP_File_Route").setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly).
              log("connecting to SFTP Server")
              .to("file://C:/myLocal").end();
        }
    };
    return builder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the FTP documentation. The file is *left as is* on the FTP server by default. You need to configure camel-ftp what it should do with the file afterwards, such as `delete=true` or any of the move options etc.

Comment: Agree, we need to delete the file after we copy the files. but here my requirements I will connecting to external SFTP server, where i will be having only read or copy access and I will not have access to move or delete the file. In this use case how to handle.

Comment: If you cannot delete or move the file, then you need to use a idempotent repository where you can store the file names of files you have already downloaded. The ftp component support using idempotent repository for that.